# How to exchange a key from an array father with an key of child element

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want to exchange the key from a father with a key of a child element, is it possible to do that?

Code:

```
$array = array(array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow"), array("e"=>"purple","f"=>"cyan","g"=>"brown","h"=>"white"));

print_r($array);
```

This is what I want to do:

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: what about `...red[b] =>...`, would the **b** stay the same, or is it only the first child with the father?

Comment: I edited my answer just now, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow"), array("e"=>"purple","f"=>"cyan","g"=>"brown","h"=>"white"));

$new_array = array();
foreach( $array as $key => $value){
        foreach ( $value as $k => $v ){
                $new_array[$k] = $value;
                foreach ( $new_array[$k] as $k1 => $v1){
                        $new_array[$k][$key] = $v1;
                        unset($new_array[$k][$k1]);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
}

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

which prints:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => green
            [c] => blue
            [d] => yellow
            [0] => red
        )

    [e] => Array
        (
            [f] => cyan
            [g] => brown
            [h] => white
            [1] => purple
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

if your array is called `$arrayOne`, then you can create `$arrayTwo` (which would contain the switch of keys) as follows:

```
<?php

  $arrayTwo = [];//initiating the array which will hold the solution
  foreach($arrayOne as $keyFather=>$valueFather)
  {
    $newKey = $valueFather[0];
    $arrayTwo = ($newKey => array());//giving child key to the original
                                     //position of the father key
                                     //and creating a new array inside

    $firstIteration = TRUE;//conditional which helps place the fathers
                           //key into the previous child key position

    //filling up the new array created:
    foreach($valueFather as $key=$otherValue)
    {
      $nextKey = $key;
      if ($firstIteration)//only iterates at the beginning of the loop
      {
        $firstIteration = FALSE;
        $nextKey = $keyFather;//giving father key to child key position
      }
      $arrayTwo[$newKey][$nextKey] = $otherValue;//saving results
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant only interchanging parent key with the first key from the "child" array - here is solution using `array_map`, `array_walk`, `array_shift`, `array_combine`, `array_values` and `current` functions:

```
$keys = array_map("key", $array);

array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k){
    $value = current($v);
    array_shift($v);
    $v[$k] = $value;
    ksort($v, SORT_NATURAL);
});

$result = array_combine($keys, array_values($array));
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
            [b] => green
            [c] => blue
            [d] => yellow
        )

    [e] => Array
        (
            [1] => purple
            [f] => cyan
            [g] => brown
            [h] => white
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

- First get the first key of the subarray.
- Append a new subarray to the array.
- Apppend a new element to the subarray.
- Delete the old element from the subarray.
- And finally, delete the old subarray.

So your code should be like this:

```
$array = array(array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow"), array("e"=>"purple","f"=>"cyan","g"=>"brown","h"=>"white"));

foreach($array as $key => $arr){
    $k = key($arr);  // get the first key of the subarray
    $array[$k] = $arr;  // append a new subarray to the array
    $array[$k][$key] = $arr[$k]; // apppend a new element to the subarray
    unset($array[$k][$k]); // delete the old element from the subarray
    unset($array[$key]); // delete the old subarray
}

// display $array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Here's the [**Live Demo**](https://eval.in/570134)